# APISIX with OpenID integration and Keycloack

Tags: openid-connect, apache-apisix

[I am trying to integrate APISIX with Keycloack on localhost. however after filling in the json data needed and from what I have been following from the official documentation, it seems I cannot get past this error:
should have required property "client_id". What could i be doing wrong?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j23gk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some problems with the way you wrote it, and only that part should be kept here. Specifically, the plugin configuration should be written here, not the entire route configuration.

[image: keep things]